# XPath, webdriver: How to get the element text?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="request-credentials-view drawer">
  <div class="tip-inner" style="width: 686px;">
    <div class="drawer-arrow" style="left: 926.55px;"></div>
    <h3 class="heading">We've sent you an email </h3>
```

Need to fetch the text "We've sent you an email". When used the bellow in x-path checker:

```
//div[@class='request-credentials-view drawer']//h3[@class='heading']//*[text()="We've sent you an email"]
```

got "No match found". Also:

```
 //div[@class='request-credentials-view drawer']//h3[(@class='heading')]//*[text()='<template>']
```

doesn't work in selenium web driver code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `contains()` function

```
//h3[contains(text(),"We've sent you an email")]
```

One thing I really like about contains is that you can do a partial match in text() specially excluding the white spaces

Comment: Got this: java.lang.AssertionError: Verify that 'Email Sent' message is displayed expected:<We've sent you an email> but was:<UnitardWebElement [webElement=null, locator=LOGIN_EMAIL_SENT_MESSAGE - xpath: //div[@class='request-credentials-view drawer']//h3[contains(text(),'<template>')]]>
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
  at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)

Comment: Can you share the test code as well if possible then?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want to rely on the element's text, use [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) to strip whitespaces around the text:

> The normalize-space function strips leading and trailing white-space
>   from a string, replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single
>   space, and returns the resulting string.

```
//h3[normalize-space(.) = "We've sent you an email"]
```

Or, you can locate the `h3` element using a CSS selector checking class attribute values along the way to the desired element:

```
div.request-credentials-view h3.heading
```

Comment: Another possible way.

Comment: Got this: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@class='request-credentials-view drawer']//h3[normalize-space(.) = '<template>' because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@id='drawer-bottom' and not(contains(@class, 'hidden'))]//div[@class='request-credentials-view drawer']//h3[normalize-space(.) = '<template>'' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: @user2340124 do you have a closing `]`?

Comment: yes, but its not working. got the below:java.lang.AssertionError: Verify that 'Email Sent' message is displayed expected:<We've sent you an email> but was:<UnitardWebElement [webElement=null, locator=LOGIN_EMAIL_SENT_MESSAGE - xpath: //div[@id='drawer-bottom' and not(contains(@class, 'hidden'))]//div[@class='request-credentials-view drawer']//h3[normalize-space(.) = '<template>']]>
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)

Comment: @user2340124 Please never post code in comments (because it is unreadable). If it is essential information, edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String message = driver.findElement(By.className("heading")).getText();
System.out.println(message);
```